# Convert positive numbers to negative and vice verca in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

In my table, positive numbers are stored as negatives and vice versa. This makes sense from an accounting point of view, however, I would like to make a select statement that returns the numbers reversed.

Example as stored in db:

```
YEAR   MONTH   REVENUE
-------------------------
2017   12      -12000,00
2017   11       -1500,00
2017   10       30000,00
```

This tells me that there was a surplus in December 2017 and a deficit in November and October.

Is there a function that does this or do I need some more advanced SQL wizardry?

Disclaimer: I understand this question might have been asked several times before. I am asking again because I am looking for a more simplified answer (if possible?)

Comment: Basic maths: `[value] * -1 = -[value]`.

Comment: `SELECT -REVENUE AS REVERSED_VALUE_YOU_FIGURE_OUT_THE_NAME_FOR_THIS` ?

Comment: Just FYI, storing positive values as negative and vice versa makes no sense anywhere. Storing X as positive and Y as negative may make sense depending on what X and Y is but if the value actually is **positive**, then don't store it as **negative**.

Comment: And a negative revenue indicates loss, not a surplus.

Comment: There you go. Thank you.
@Lasse: I am not defending the logic of negative vs positive when it comes to surplus/loss, however there is no way for me to change that.

Comment: Can't we just reverse the polarity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in comment multiply by -1

```
Select
Year,
Month,
Revenue * -1 as Revenue
From Table
```

Comment: Or simply `-Revenue`.